# what is the practical use of void datatype and void pointer?

Tags: c#, c, void, void-pointers

Void variable has nothing to do and also void pointer can only be pointed with casting.
So void pointer is used when we actually don't know where and of which data type we want to point. But what is of void variable?

Any practical example?

Comment: You mean `void v;`? That doesn't exist in any language.

Comment: I think its more related to `C` than C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C `void` can't be considered a data type, it is a keyword used as a placeholder in place of a data type to show that actually there is no data.

For example consider the function `void f(void);`. Here the keyword void is used to mean the absence of any parameters passed and returned values.

But `void *ptr;` is different in meaning.

This declares a pointer without specifying which data type it is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no void variable, but there are void pointers.
As the others have mentioned a lot, I would like to remind you to type cast before using void pointers.

```
float generic_add(void *n1, void *n2){
    return *((int *) n1) + *((float *) n2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

void pointers are very useful for memory allocation purposes, when we don't have knowledge about the exact datatype. Try to write your own malloc to get sense of void *.

or read
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `void` variable, as marko Topolnik states in his comment.

`Void` pointers are used in C/C++ to point to something unspecified.  The keyword is also used (and in C# and other languages) to mark methods that do not return a value.  So I think you are thinking:

```
void method();
```

is returning something of type `void`, which it is not.  It is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

They're useful in a generic interface, like the classic `qsort`.

```
void
 qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
     int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/qsort/

The `void` return type identifies this as a procedure rather than a function, because it returns no data at all (of any type). The `void *`s can point to anything at all, but the `compar` function has to cast them appropriately in order to use them.